# Cant add PHP 5 Interpreter on Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm currently trying to add the Codeigniter framework to Netbeans. I followed all instructions to download the plugin as noted here : https://kenai.com/projects/nbphpci/pages/NBInstall , but after all is done and Netbeans is restarted, I try to create a new project but an error comes up saying

> **PHP Interpreter must be selected**

I tried pointing it to my `php.exe` file found in my WAMP directory `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe` but still nothing... any ideas? I attached an image where the error shows (in the options window)

[image: Netbeans Options Window interpreter error]

Comment: Maybe this instruction helps: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to localize the `php.exe` file.

If you are using `xampp` it is located in `c:\xampp\php\php.exe`

In case you are using `wamp` it is located in `c:\wamp\bin\php\php.exe`

Answer (score 7):

If you see the message above you have to...

1. Download xampp latest version from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html.
2. After you run netbeans, you get the error message above you should
   click the "Browse" button.
3. Go to `xampp` folder for example `C:\xampp`
4. Click on PHP folder `C:\xampp\php`
5. Click on `php.exe` to tell neatbeans the interpreter directory location. (because it does not come with netbeans package) `xampp\php\php.exe`

Answer (score 3):

Run Netbeans as  administrator
So you can set your path in the php setting

Comment: This was the solution to my issue with Netbeans version 11.1